# ArgumentException: Requested value 'X86' was not found

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, exception, admob, google-mobile-ads

i try to import GoogleMobileAds sdk to unity. when i import PlayServicesResolver package, i am getting error on console like this 'ArgumentException: Requested value 'X86' was not found.' I cant figure out why?

> ArgumentException: Requested value 'X86' was not found.
>   System.Enum+EnumResult.SetFailure (System.Enum+ParseFailureKind failure, System.String failureMessageID, System.Object failureMessageFormatArgument) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
>   System.Enum.TryParseEnum (System.Type enumType, System.String value, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Enum+EnumResult& parseResult) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
>   System.Enum.Parse (System.Type enumType, System.String value, System.Boolean ignoreCase) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
>   System.Enum.Parse (System.Type enumType, System.String value) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
>   GooglePlayServices.AndroidAbis.EnumValueStringToULong (System.Type enumType, System.String enumValueString) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/AndroidAbis.cs:220)
>   GooglePlayServices.AndroidAbis.get_Current () (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/AndroidAbis.cs:278)
>   GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.m__1B () (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1201)
>   GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver+PropertyPoller`1[T].Poll (System.Func`1[TResult] getCurrentValue, GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver+PropertyPoller`1+Changed[T] changed) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:278)
>   GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.PollAndroidAbis () (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1201)
>   UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:303)

Comment: I am using Unity3d 2019.3.0a3 by the way.

Comment: This happens because
from unity 2019.3.01f support for x86 architecture is entirely removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something is wrong with this version.

I'm running 2019.3.0a3 on Mac and have the same error... Sadly I didn't saw it before importing my project and kinda of lost everything, because I can't downgrade my project properly.

My solution is not the best, but here's what I've done:

- Downloaded the latest stable build 2019.1.4f1
- Created a new project using this build
- Copied all the files from my previous project and pasted it inside my new project folder (export package in 2019.3.0a3 not working as well... how great!)
- Recreated all my scenes because pasting the files is not enough to replicate them

Aaaaand that's it, hard work but I think it should do (I'm currently doing it right now, I hope it works).

Also, as this is not the best solution, I wished to write it as a comment and not an answer, but my reputation here is kinda low yet.

Cya, good luck with your project and update us if you have any solution better than mine!

Comment: You are right. It's about this version i think too. I just build at 2019.a.4f1 version just like you sad and exception gone. Thank you for your advises.

Answer (score 17):

You can solve this issue in Unity 2019.3 [as mentioned in GitHub googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/230). You just need newer version of Play Services Resolver than v1.2.115.

1. download a release archive from GitHub [googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/releases). be aware the note below.
2. extract files from the archive, and go to its root directory
3. run build as described in [Building from Source in README.md](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver#building-from-source), and you will get a unity package file at ./build/plugin.unitypackage. You may need to install modules in Unity if you lack something in Unity. (e.g. iOS Build Support)
4. in the project window on Unity, delete */Assets/PlayServicesResolver* folder
5. on Unity, import all files from the package file that you built at step 3 above

NOTE: In my environment, v1.2.115 failed at its build because of error CS0619, so I chose v1.2.124 instead. With this version, build succeeded and is working good with Unity 2019.3.0a12 for me so far.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I resolved the issue but just importing the .unitypackage into my project. You don't need to build from source in order to fix it.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, @YoanPumar. I didn't notice that the package file is already composed in the release archive file. I confirmed that play-services-resolver-x.x.xxx.x.unitypackage (x is number) placed under the root dir in a release archive has all the same contents.

Answer (score 3):

I think i found that why i am getting this exception. In Unity3d 2019.3.0a3 version, there is no x86 option at Project Settings-> Player-> Target Architectures. But in older version of Unity3d, there is. Maybe the imported PlayServicesResolver sdk search for this option too, so throws ArgumentException.

Answer (score 3):

I've been having the same issue. I've update the PlayServicesResolver from GitHub instead of though Unity and it seems to have fixed the issue:

https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

Answer (score 3):

Simplified version of this that worked for me, without having to rebuild.

Used with version Unity 2019.3f6

1. download a release archive from GitHub googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver.
2. extract files from the archive
3. From Unity Assets > Import Package import the play-services-resolver-1... in the downloaded file.

This automatically removed unwanted directories, etc.

Comment: And for those who despaired, restart Unity after import and errors are gone :)
Thank you, David Clayton

Answer (score 1):

For me , deleting the PlayServicesResolver directory worked.

Comment: same , i deleted the resolver and external dependency manager folders inside Assets/ folder and problem gone